# Adding an n-diagonal matrix in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset like the following:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                 ID  Con An Bc Dd Kl Fp
                  a1    1   1   1  1 10 3
                  a2    3   1   0  0 11 4
                  a3    4   0   0  0 12 a6
                  a4    3   1   1  0 21 a8
                  a5    4   1   1  1 22 7
                  a6    2   0   0  0 90 d
                  ")
dat
  ID Con An Bc Dd Kl Fp
1 a1   1  1  1  1 10  3
2 a2   3  1  0  0 11  4
3 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6
4 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8
5 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7
6 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d
```

I want to repeat each row for n (here `n=4`) times and put row index for each original row and sort the table by `ID`.

```
dat1= cbind(dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), 4), ], Ind = rep(1:4, each = nrow(dat)))
dat2= dat1[order(dat1$ID),] 
dat2
    ID Con An Bc Dd Kl Fp Ind
1   a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   1
1.1 a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   2
1.2 a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   3
1.3 a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   4
2   a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   1
2.1 a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   2
2.2 a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   3
2.3 a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   4
3   a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   1
3.1 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   2
3.2 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   3
3.3 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   4
4   a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   1
4.1 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   2
4.2 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   3
4.3 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   4
5   a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   1
5.1 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   2
5.2 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   3
5.3 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   4
6   a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   1
6.1 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   2
6.2 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   3
6.3 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   4
```

Now, I want to get a new indicator variable `Ind2` based on the following criteria:

```
dat2$Ind2 <- ifelse(dat2$Con == dat2$Ind, 1, 0)
dat2
    ID Con An Bc Dd Kl Fp Ind Ind2
1   a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   1   1
1.1 a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   2   0
1.2 a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   3   0
1.3 a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   4   0
2   a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   1   0
2.1 a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   2   0
2.2 a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   3   1
2.3 a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   4   0
3   a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   1   0
3.1 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   2   0
3.2 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   3   0
3.3 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   4   1
4   a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   1   0
4.1 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   2   0
4.2 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   3   1
4.3 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   4   0
5   a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   1   0
5.1 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   2   0
5.2 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   3   0
5.3 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   4   1
6   a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   1   0
6.1 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   2   1
6.2 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   3   0
6.3 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   4   0
```

At last, I need to include a 4 by 4 matrix and repeat it in each n (here, n=4) rows. I need an easy fix to import these matrices.

```
   ID Con An Bc Dd Kl Fp Ind Ind2 Con1 Con2 Con3 Con4
1  a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   1   1    1    0    0    0
2  a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   2   0    0    1    0    0
3  a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   3   0    0    0    1    0
4  a1   1  1  1  1 10  3   4   0    0    0    0    1
5  a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   1   0    1    0    0    0
6  a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   2   0    0    1    0    0
7  a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   3   1    0    0    1    0
8  a2   3  1  0  0 11  4   4   0    0    0    0    1
9  a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   1   0    1    0    0    0
10 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   2   0    0    1    0    0
11 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   3   0    0    0    1    0
12 a3   4  0  0  0 12 a6   4   1    0    0    0    1
13 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   1   0    1    0    0    0
14 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   2   0    0    1    0    0
15 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   3   1    0    0    1    0
16 a4   3  1  1  0 21 a8   4   0    0    0    0    1
17 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   1   0    1    0    0    0
18 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   2   0    0    1    0    0
19 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   3   0    0    0    1    0
20 a5   4  1  1  1 22  7   4   1    0    0    0    1
21 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   1   0    1    0    0    0
22 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   2   1    0    1    0    0
23 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   3   0    0    0    1    0
24 a6   2  0  0  0 90  d   4   0    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: You can try `setNames(cbind(dat2, diag(4)), c(names(dat2), paste0("Con", 1:4)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` way starting from your original data `dat` :

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- 4

dat %>%
  uncount(n) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Ind = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()  %>%
  mutate(Ind2 = as.integer(Con == Ind)) -> dat2

bind_cols(dat2, map_dfc(seq_len(n), 
          ~dat2 %>% transmute(!!paste0('Cond', .x) := as.integer(Ind == .x))))

#    ID      Con    An    Bc    Dd    Kl Fp      Ind  Ind2 Cond1 Cond2 Cond3 Cond4
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 a1        1     1     1     1    10 3         1     1     1     0     0     0
# 2 a1        1     1     1     1    10 3         2     0     0     1     0     0
# 3 a1        1     1     1     1    10 3         3     0     0     0     1     0
# 4 a1        1     1     1     1    10 3         4     0     0     0     0     1
# 5 a2        3     1     0     0    11 4         1     0     1     0     0     0
# 6 a2        3     1     0     0    11 4         2     0     0     1     0     0
# 7 a2        3     1     0     0    11 4         3     1     0     0     1     0
# 8 a2        3     1     0     0    11 4         4     0     0     0     0     1
# 9 a3        4     0     0     0    12 a6        1     0     1     0     0     0
#10 a3        4     0     0     0    12 a6        2     0     0     1     0     0
# … with 14 more rows
```